# `xp_cmdshell` SQL Server - privillages for user authenticated by password and name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to make it possible to call procedure `xp_cmdshell`  for user authenticated by password and username ? At this moment, user authenticated by windows authentiation can call this procedure.

My SQL Server is 2012.

Comment: What permissions do you have enabled for this user in their AD logon that you don't for their sql authentication account?

Comment: simply, it login by jdbc and this app is running on linux. It is not possible (from what I know) to login by jdbc by windows authentication from linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant that user execute on xp_cmdshell

Then set up the xp_cmdshell_proxy_account

When xp_cmdshell is called by a user that is not a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, xp_cmdshell connects to Windows by using the account name and password stored in the credential named ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##. If this proxy credential does not exist, xp_cmdshell will fail.

The proxy account credential can be created by executing sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. As arguments, this stored procedure takes a Windows user name and password.

Comment: Could you tell me how to create this proxy user step by step ?  Is it possible to call other procedure as windows authenticated user?

Comment: `EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'account_name' , 'password'` I would use a separate AD account from anything else so you can have some visibility to what the user is doing if you have any monitoring tools. I would not use the SQL service account. When the user calls xp_cmdshell it shells out to the OS as the proxy user.

Comment: Tell me please, how to create this proxy. Moreover, how to call stored procedure `A` as proxy user?

Comment: Have your AD admin create an AD user account. Then armed with the user and password, have a SQL sysadmin log in to SQL Server with SSMS, open a query window, and run the statement `EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'account_name' , 'password'` where account_name is the one you received from the AD admin.

Comment: but where you define what procedure you call ?

Comment: The procedure sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account is the one that creates the proxy credentials. The procedure xp_cmdshell is the procedure the sql user authenticated by name and password calls to shell out to the OS and do some work. xp_cmdshell needs the credentials created by sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account in order to work for the non-sysadmin user. You only run the sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy one time in order to set up the credentials. After that, the user just calls xp_cmdshell when they need it.

Comment: in SSMS query window you call sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account to set up the proxy account. An alternative way to set up the proxy account is to execute this statement instead `create credential ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## with identity = 'username', secret = 'password'
` After this the user should be able to call xp_cmdshell

Comment: So something like that: `CREATE PROCEDURE......EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'account_name' , 'password'     ;     exec  xp_cmdshell '....'` Yeah ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134714/discussion-between-millhoused-and-llvm-questioner).